# How to use FnFilter() to get the exact match in multiselect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do I pass the multiple values in FnFilter() and get the exact match?

I am using "fnFilter" to get the exact match - 
fnFilter("^"+searchString+"$", 18, true, false); and I made "bsmart:false"

I have values like 10, 100,101,102, 1000 and I have given a multiselect checkbox option.

If I select the individual value filter works fine . However if I select multiple values if not filtering only the exact match.

Example: If i select 10 filter works fine, however if I select 10 and 101, the values will get filtered for 100 as well.

Please suggest me how to handle this issue in FnFilter for multiselects?

Thanks in Advance
Ganesh

Comment: if you select 10 and 100 what will be the value of searchString

Comment: if I select 10 and 100 it works fine. SearchString value will be 10|100..  If i select 10 and 1000 searchString value will be 10|1000 but it filters 100 as well

Comment: How are you performing the **and**?

Comment: FnFilter is doing everything. I am just passing the searchString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is the problem, I think it should be something like `(10|1000)`...

Your regex `10|1000` looks for a string that is either starting with `10` or ending with `1000` so `100` is satisfying the condition.

Comment: I checked my code again.. If i select 10 and 101 then also its filtering with 100. My regex is 10|101.. its still filtering 100

Comment: @Ganesh the problem is the part `^10|` which says if the value starts with `10` then the test is true

Comment: Yeah its because of ^10| ....i tired with (10|100) its not working. Can I split the values as array and send the values one by one to fnFilter using for loop  like this?-->...fnFilter(^10$, 18, true, false);    fnFilter(^100$, 18, true, false);

Comment: Hi,

I have used your approach and it worked with slight modification. I did like this

searchString="(10|100|1000)";
oTable.fnFilter(searchString+"$", 18, true, false);

If I give `^` in the beginning it doesn't work. I need to specify only end of the searchString using `$`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Working code

```
searchString='(10|100|1000|10000)';
oTable.FnFilter(searchString+'$', column_number, true, false);
```

Need to specify only end of the search string and not start of the string. Seach String should be enclosed with ( )